# Help identifying a bead shaped passive component

Tags: identification

Could anyone help me identify the blue components on this picture ? (I don't care about the value)

The symbol underneath looks like a coil in a box.

The PCB comes from an old VCR.

Thanks !

[image]

Comment: the symbol that you described is an inductor ... check the symbols under other components ... see if they match the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are just inductors. Their values can be decoded from the coloured dots in a way similar to decoding resistor color codes.